# Laravel mapWithKeys() returns single value

Tags: laravel

In laravel I'm getting `products` array that looks like this

```
dd($activity->load('products'));
```

```
"products": [

    {
    "id": 1,
    "pivot": {
    "activity_id": 1,
    "product_id": 10,
    "quantity": 16
    }
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "pivot": {
    "activity_id": 1,
    "product_id": 11,
    "quantity": 20
    }
    }

]
```

I want to get an array of objects and pluck only the `pivot.product_id` and `pivot.quantity` from the `products` array

Expected result:

```
"selected_products": [

    {
    "id": 10,
    "quantity": 16 
    },
    {
    "id": 11,
    "quantity": 20
    }

]
```

What I tried

```
return $activity
->load('products')
->products()
->get()
->mapWithKeys(function ($product, $key) {
   return ['id' => $product->pivot->product_id, 'quantity' => $product->pivot->quantity];
});
```

Result

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "quantity": 16
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems on your code.

First, `load('products')` is redundant. You cam simple call `$activity->products`. Or if you need filter on the `products` , use `$activity->products()->where(...)->get()`

Second, you should use `map` for indexed array. `mapWithKeys` is using for associative array.

```
return $activity->products
->map(function ($product, $key) {
   return ['id' => $product->pivot->product_id, 'quantity' => $product->pivot->quantity];
});
```

Comment: I later on changed it to `map()` and it worked but I had no idea why and you just enlightened me. Thanks a bunch. Btw do I have to call `toArray()` since `map()` returns a collection or no need?